# Can an experienced manual tester take the Advanced Technical Certification exam?

Tags: certification

my question is about whether an experienced manual tester who has istqb foundation test certification but with no automation experience can take the Advanced Technical Certification exam?

Comment: Do you mean https://www.astqb.org/advanced-tester/ ?

Comment: Also see https://www.astqb.org/road-map/

Comment: yes I am interested in either ASTQB or ISQTB Advanced Technical Test Analyst certification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Provided you have your ISTQB Foundation, you can take the Advanced Technical Test Analyst course and exam.

The roadmap can be found on [ISTQB's website](https://www.istqb.org/certification-path-root.html), with more information on the course content [here](https://www.istqb.org/certification-path-root/advanced-level/advanced-level-technical-test-analyst.html).

Edit: I've previously worked with a functional test manager who took the technical test analyst course and, unfortunately, failed. I think he found it harder without any automation experience as one of the modules is Test Tools and Automation... that doesn't make it impossible though.

Comment: If I don't have project experience in automation testing. How can I better prepare for ISTQB Advanced Technical Test Analyst exam?

Comment: Time to get the text books out :) Also have a look at the syllabus, objectives, outcomes and exam structure on the ISTQB website so you have a clear understanding of what's expected (https://www.istqb.org/certification-path-root/test-automation-engineer.html - look down the left hand side for your course details)

Comment: Thank you.:) what's the best place to go to if I have got any questions in regards to the study material?